# google test - Checking two different functionalities with single piece of code

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

What is a correct way to use one implementation of unit test to test two completely different functionalities. In other words, I would like to have two (or more) tests that execute identical code for testing, but differ only in one place - just like in the code below:

```
TEST(SomeClass, someFunctionality)
{
    // Initialize test (identical)
    // ...

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 128; i++) {

        // Prepare iteration (identical)
        // ...

        // One test calls here function A() and second test calls function B()
        // and here is the only difference - multiple lines computing arguments
        // for each function call
        // ...

        // Finalize iteration (identical)
        // ...
    }

    // Finalize test (identical)
    // ...
}
```

Comment: You have a very specific problem yet you provide only a very vague and abstract explanation. Google test provides functions for setup and tear down, use them. Extract method for the rest of the common code.

Comment: Factor out common functions and make two tests that utilize those.

Comment: Take a look at the [googletest doc: same data multiple tests](http://google.github.io/googletest/primer.html#same-data-multiple-tests).

Comment: None of above can accomodate the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a function that both tests share, and pass it a lambda containing the code unique to each test:

```
template<typename Func>
void testFunctionality(Func func)
{
    // Initialize test
    // ...

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 128; i++) {

        // Prepare iteration
        // ...

        func();

        // Finalize iteration
        // ...
    }

    // Finalize test
    // ...
}

TEST(SomeClass, someFunctionality)
{
    testFunctionality([]() { A(); });
}
TEST(SomeClass, someOtherFunctionality)
{
    testFunctionality([]() { B(); });
}
```

You can pass the lambda function whatever arguments you need, e.g. the current iteration `i` or other local parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, this is what was llooking for